# Is there a way to refer to external drive by its name other than the letter?

Tags: windows

Say I have a external drive with name Drive A assigned to letter E in Windows. Is there a way I can access this particular drive with name Drive A rather than E example "Drive A:/test.word"

Answer (score 1):

Negative answer : This is not supported in Windows.

If you need to convert the disk-label to its drive-letter, see the post
[Refer to/select a drive based only on its label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849/refer-to-select-a-drive-based-only-on-its-label-i-e-not-the-drive-letter)